# how to put alert on selecting bootstrap multiselect ckeckbox?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using `bootstrap multiselect`. I want to generate a `alert` when a particular check box is checked.

my html looks like below

```
<label>Particulars :</label>
    <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="DS Form">DS Form</option>
        <option class="proof" value="Proofs">Proofs</option>
        <option value="Banners">Banners</option>
        <option value="IRCTC Form">IRCTC Form</option>
        <option value="R3 Form Returned">R3 Form Returned</option>
        <option value="Declaration Form">Declaration Form</option>
        <option value="Agent Declaration Form">Sub Agent Declaration Form</option>
        <option value="Old Tokens">Old Tokens</option>
        <option value="11">Registration Form </option>
        <option value="12">12</option> 
</select>
```

I want to generate a alert when proofs checkbox is checked.

I tried below code

```
 if( $('.multiselect-container>li>a>label>input[type=checkbox][value="proofs"]').prop("checked") == true)){
        alert("proofs checked");
    }
```

but its not working can any one help me.

Comment: put your fiddle code here

Comment: the code you are trying is incomplete or you have missed while posting. It should have if condition or something while checking ==true. Please provide the proper code or fiddle link.

Comment: yes true even its not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChange` event of `bootstrap multiselect` to get the selected option. As mentioned in your question, the below code only checks for `Proofs` and alerts user.

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    onChange: function (element, checked) {
 if (checked === true) {
    if ($(element).val() == "Proofs")  alert("proofs checked");
 }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<label>Particulars :</label>
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="DS Form">DS Form</option>
 <option class="proof" value="Proofs">Proofs</option>
 <option value="Banners">Banners</option>
 <option value="IRCTC Form">IRCTC Form</option>
 <option value="R3 Form Returned">R3 Form Returned</option>
 <option value="Declaration Form">Declaration Form</option>
 <option value="Agent Declaration Form">Sub Agent Declaration Form</option>
 <option value="Old Tokens">Old Tokens</option>
 <option value="11">Registration Form </option>
 <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#checkboxid').change(function() {
    if ($('#checkboxid').prop('checked')) {
        //checked - insert code here
    }
    else {
        //not checked - insert code here
    }
});
```

Comment: that check boxes are coming dynamically , in my code i did not mention any where checkbox it will come dynamically  and not able to add id's to them